# Possible to get a list of images in subscription using ARM templates?

Tags: image, azure, templates

Is it possible, in an Azure ARM template, to get a list of images for a subscription?

I'm using ARM templates for deployments. For the image parameter, I want to have users select from a list of images in their account. As of now they have to find the image's Resource Id and pasting that into the field.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot really achieve that, you can write a script you users can run before the deployment to find that out. probably closest you can get with hacks

ARM templates do not really allow picking anything before deployment, you have to pass in parameters

Comment: ARM Templates are declarative, which mean you have to state what you want.